# HTML5 - WebRTC how can i record the

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, webrtc

I have a `<video id=d1 src=webm.webm>`
which is playing a video and audio music.

Now how can i press "record" and copy the audio stream, which i want to record lets say duration wise or from start till current or current-5second .. i mean some random way to capture the running audio like clone replay for some spectrum analyzing later.

```
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, function(stream){
    console.log("Received local stream");
    d1.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    localstream = stream;       
  }, function(e){
    console.log("getUserMedia error: ", e);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this repo, perhaps you can find some useful: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC